# Анимация по дуге в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Подскажите как сделать анимацию летящей вращающейся картинки по дуге? В моем случае нужно сделать вращение елочной игрушки по заданной траектории

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Саму дугу я сделаю бесцветной (для наглядности пока стоит)

На метаните видел реализацию бегающего по канвасу шарика, но не смог подстроить под себя. Все через code behind

Сама дуга ниже:

```
                Point btn1Point = ((Button)sender).TransformToAncestor(main).Transform(new Point(-25, 0));
            Line l = new Line();
            l.X1 = btn1Point.X + ((Button)sender).ActualWidth;
            l.Y1 = btn1Point.Y + ((Button)sender).ActualHeight / 2;

            System.Windows.Shapes.Path snowball_path = new System.Windows.Shapes.Path()
            {
                Stroke = Brushes.LightBlue,
                StrokeThickness = 6.0,
                StrokeStartLineCap = System.Windows.Media.PenLineCap.Round,
                StrokeEndLineCap = System.Windows.Media.PenLineCap.Round
            };
            Canvas cnv = new Canvas();
            PathFigureCollection pfc = new PathFigureCollection();
            PathGeometry pg = new PathGeometry();
            PathFigure pf = new PathFigure();
            pf.StartPoint = new Point(l.X1, l.Y1);
            ArcSegment a = new ArcSegment(new Point(1600, 150), new Size(1, 2), 87, true, SweepDirection.Clockwise, true);





            cnv.Children.Add(snowball_path);
            snowball_path.Data = pg;
            pfc.Add(pf);
            pg.Figures = pfc;
            pf.Segments.Add(a);

            main.Children.Insert(0, cnv);
```

---

Сейчас застрял на таком моменте:
У меня есть PathGeometry дуги, как по ней запустить картинку?

```
Image snowball = new Image();
snowball.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "images/snowball.png")));

DoubleAnimationUsingPath animation = new DoubleAnimationUsingPath
{
     PathGeometry = pg,
     Duration = new TimeSpan(5)
};
snowball.BeginAnimation(Image.WidthProperty, animation);
```

Что писать в

```
snowball.BeginAnimation(Image.WidthProperty, animation);
```

сейчас ничего по дуге не проходит, а хотелось бы картинку

**

### Последняя наработка:

**

```
                DoubleAnimationUsingPath animation1 = new DoubleAnimationUsingPath
            {
                PathGeometry = pg,

                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)),
                RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever,
                AutoReverse = true,
                SpeedRatio = 1
            };

            snowball.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, animation1);
```

Шарик бегает по верхней границе экрана, не по дуге

### **Последняя наработка 2.0_Final**

```
                Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
            r.Name = "snowball";
            r.Width = 60;
            r.Height = 60;
            r.Margin = (sender as Button).Margin;
            r.Fill = new ImageBrush
            {
                ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "images/snowball.png")))
            };

            ThicknessAnimation snowball_throw_animation = new ThicknessAnimation();
            snowball_throw_animation.To = new Thickness(1250, -800, 0, 0);
            snowball_throw_animation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5));

            snowball_throw_animation.Completed += new EventHandler(snowball_throw_animation_Completed);
            r.BeginAnimation(Rectangle.MarginProperty, snowball_throw_animation);

            main.Children.Add(r);
```

Сделал по прямой линии, может кому пригодится (*с дугой не получилось)

### **Последняя наработка 3.0_Final_2.0**

Ответ для дуги: как писал @Андрей NOP в комментариях

> а нужно анимировать TranslateTransform.XProperty и TranslateTransform.YProperty

Добавьте еще RotateProperty для Rectangle (собственно, у него можно сделать .Fill картинку) и будет счастье! Я все-таки сделал по дуге (ну как сделал, я увидел, что летит не по прямой, а дальше мне было лень координаты задавать).

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.animation.pointanimationusingpath?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @Андрей NOP, я пытался, не получилось

Comment: *Шарик бегает по верхней границе экрана, не по дуге* — вы анимировали только `Left`, нужно еще и `Top`: https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/16.4.php

Comment: @АндрейNOP, я делал и так. В том, что я написал (самое последнее) я анимирую канвас, а нужно анимировать TranslateTransform.XProperty и TranslateTransform.YProperty, однако результата не дало. Я делал (пытался) анимацию по прямой линии, тоже не вышло) уже не знаю куда копать.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, https://pastebin.com/uYuThKp1 вот тут я сделал через XAML, и шарик бегает по дуге. Но не так как нужно. Можете подсказать как вместо  <PathFigure IsClosed="True" StartPoint="110,110"> прописать StartPoint? в коде эта координата у меня есть (появляется по клику на кнопку). Еще момент в этом XAML в том, что я не знаю как настроить RoutedEvent="Button.Loaded" для моего события по клику на кнопку (сами кнопки также динамически создаются)